# Using async: true in multiple AJAX requests

Tags: jquery

When you use the `$.when` function with multiple AJAX requests, can you set `async: true` so that all AJAX requests fire off at once?

My below example is working, but I'm wondering if all AJAX calls are working asynchronously using this method.

```js
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
  // the code here will be executed when all four ajax requests resolve.
  // a1, a2, a3 and a4 are lists of length 3 containing the response text,
  // status, and jqXHR object for each of the four ajax calls respectively.
});

function ajax1() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "someUrl",
      dataType: "json",
      data: yourJsonData;
    },
    async: true
  });
}

function ajax2() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "someUrl",
      dataType: "json",
      data: yourJsonData;
    },
    async: true
  });
}

function ajax3() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "someUrl",
      dataType: "json",
      data: yourJsonData;
    },
    async: true
  });
}

function ajax4() {
  return $.ajax({
      url: "someUrl",
      dataType: "json",
      data: yourJsonData;
    },
    async: true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `async: true` is the default state so you don't need to set it explicitly.

Secondly, I'm not sure how that code is working as supplying two arguments to `$.ajax()` means the first should be a string which contains the URL and the second should be the settings object. In addition there's an extra `}` and also a `;` after the `data` property, both of which will be causing syntax errors. The code itself can be simplified to this:

```js
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2(), ajax3(), ajax4()).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
  console.log('all requests complete');
});

function ajaxN() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    dataType: "json",
    data: yourJsonData
  });
}

// repeated functions...
```

> I'm wondering if all AJAX calls are working asynchronously using this method.

Yes, they will be. However the number of concurrent requests a client can make will be limited by their browser and also the configuration of the receiving server. There's nothing you can do to amend that in client JS alone. This is part of the reason why it's bad practice to send a lot of async requests at the same time.